# Perl weird behaviour in number with decimal point

Tags: perl, floating-point, decimal

So I was writing a perl program to do some calculation and
I had put a floating point number as

`$x = 00.05;`

if I print

`print $x * 100.0;`

It returns 500.0

But if I do

`$x = 0.05;
 print $x * 100.0;`

it prints correctly 5.0;

What is this behaviour?
Is there any convention I have to obey that I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A leading zero means an octal constant, so when you do

```
my $x = 00.05;
```

you actually do string concatenation of two octal numbers:

```
my $x = 00 . 05; # The same as "0" . "5"
```

which gives you the string `"05"` and later you do

```
print $x * 100.0;  # prints 500
```

since `perl` interprets as `"05"` as the number `5`